# jQuery - .hide() and negative space leftover

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to hide elements based on a series of checkboxes and I noticed that while it will hide the elements, it still leaves space as if they were there.

Is there any way to perform this action so that the hidden elements don't take up space?

```js
var cards = $('.resource-card');
var resourceHeaders = $('.resource-header');

function filterResourceCards() {
    var checked = $("#filter-section :checkbox:checked");
    if (checked.length) {
        cards.hide();
        resourceHeaders.hide();
        checked.each(function () {
            $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn(500);
        });
    } else {
        cards.fadeIn(500);
        resourceHeaders.fadeIn(500);
    }
}

$('#filter-section :checkbox').click(filterResourceCards);
// filterResourceCards();
```

**EDIT:** Full [Codepen](https://codepen.io/devin1229/pen/gOWJLqr) example.

Comment: adding the html and css would be helpful, maybe create a snippet here.

Comment: `hide()` uses `display: none`, so the space shouldn't be kept there. This is the difference between `display: none` and `visibility: invisible`

Comment: @Towkir it's kind of long, so I made a Codepen: https://codepen.io/devin1229/pen/gOWJLqr 

In this example I only have 3 groups, but in reality I have more. When you start filtering group 3+ you can see more negative space being added.

Comment: The parent-child relationship matters. If you view the source in browser you can see that the container div "resource-cards" (with the "s") is still visible. You're hiding the child divs "resource-card" (without the "s") successfully.

Comment: Hmmm.. I see.

However, if I add a variable ```var container = $(".resource-cards");``` and then include ```container.hide();``` to the if/else statement, nothing shows when you activate a checkbox - everything hides.

Answer (score 0):

You have margin added in the parent element, and hiding the child element only makes the parent element `0` in height, but the space in the margin remains.

Try moving the

```css
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
```

from `.resource-cards` to `.resource-card`. I mean move it to the child element.

Something like this:

```js
var cards = $(".resource-card");
var resourceHeaders = $(".resource-header");

function filterResourceCards() {
  var checked = $("#filter-section :checkbox:checked");
  if (checked.length) {
    cards.hide();
    resourceHeaders.hide();
    checked.each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn(500);
    });
  } else {
    cards.fadeIn(500);
    resourceHeaders.fadeIn(500);
    // resourceContainers.fadeIn(500);
  }
}

$("#filter-section :checkbox").click(filterResourceCards);
filterResourceCards();
```

```css
.resource-cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.resource-card {
  flex: 0 1 calc(23% - 1em);
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e5bc73;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /* 
  margin: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  */
  margin: 20px 15px 50px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .resource-card {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
}

.resource-card-header {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/75");
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "AleckCdBold";
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.resource-card-content {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.resource-card-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.resource-card .tag {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "AleckCdRegular";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.resource-card-body .title {
  color: #1e1e1e;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  font-family: "AleckCdBold";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="filter-section">
  <input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="group1" id="group1"><label for="group1" class="filter-label">Group 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="group2" id="group2"><label for="onboarding" class="filter-label">Group 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="group3" value="group3" id="group3"><label for="onboarding" class="filter-label">Group 3</label>

  <!--Group 1-->
  <div class="resource-header">
    <h5>Group 1</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="resource-card-container">
    <div class="resource-cards">
      <div class="resource-card group1">
        <div class="resource-card-header">
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card-content">
          <div class="resource-card-body">
            <p class="tag">Header</p>
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p>Short Description Here</p>
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-footer">
            <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="resource-card group1">
        <div class="resource-card-header">
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card-content">
          <p class="tag">Header</p>
          <p class="title">Title</p>
          <p>Short Description Here</p>
          <div class="resource-card-footer">
            <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Group 2-->

    <div class="resource-header">
      <h5>Group 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="resource-card-container">
      <div class="resource-cards">
        <div class="resource-card group2">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <div class="resource-card-body">
              <p class="tag">Header</p>
              <p class="title">Title</p>
              <p>Short Description Here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card group2">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <p class="tag">Header</p>
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p>Short Description Here</p>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card group2">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <p class="tag">Header</p>
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p>Short Description Here</p>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card group2">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <p class="tag">Header</p>
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p>Short Description Here</p>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Group 3-->

    <div class="resource-card-container">
      <div class="resource-header">
        <h5>
          </i>Group 3</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="resource-cards">
        <div class="resource-card group3">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <div class="resource-card-body">
              <p class="tag">Header</p>
              <p class="title">Title</p>
              <p>Short Description Here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card group3">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <p class="tag">Header</p>
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p>Short Description Here</p>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card group3">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <p class="tag">Header</p>
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p>Short Description Here</p>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resource-card group3">
          <div class="resource-card-header">
          </div>
          <div class="resource-card-content">
            <p class="tag">Header</p>
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p>Short Description Here</p>
            <div class="resource-card-footer">
              <div class="link-button" href="#">Go</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```